# Bash history inconsistent text

Tags: oh-my-zsh, iterm2

When in terminal and pressing the up arrow to go through my bash history the line will often get messed up. This is especially true when the history is multiline or has special characters in it.

It's difficult to provide and example, but if my history is:

```
1 echo hello world
2 export foo=bar
3 cat /my/file.txt
```

Then pushing up will give me first `cat /my/file.txt` then `export foo=bar` and then it may break and do something like `execho hello world`. Going back down then will stay broken.

My bash prompt is:

```
echo $PS1
%(?:%{%}➜ :%{%}➜ ) %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)
```

I'm assuming there's an issue with my bash prompt, but I would hate to change it as I'm accustomed to the look/style. Would hopefully be able to find a solution.

Comment: Note that most likely it's only a display issue; the line might appear broken, but there shouldn't be any damage and commands will still execute correctly

Comment: Correct, that appears to be the case. However if I want to scroll left/right to edit the line and change something it becomes impossible to do.

Comment: It could be related to the terminal emulator you are using. Which terminal emulator are you using on which local OS? What is $TERM set to? Are you running bash locally, or ssh to a remote system? If so, what is the remote system type? One tag suggests you are using iterm2, while the other tag suggests you are using zsh (which is not bash).

Comment: $TERM is set to: xterm-256color. I'm running macOS. I am using zsh in iterm2.

Comment: It looks like the issue is with some of the zsh themes, went through a few themes - some work fine and others don't.